# React Native: Passing props between components and componentWillMount() method

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, prop

I'm using React Native 0.43. I've two components, named `ParentComponent` and `ChildComponent`. I want to pass some props from parent to child component. I'm using following code (abridged version) in parent component:

```
export default class ParentComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: 34.7821,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ChildComponent latitude={this.state.latitude} />
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

My child component is as following:

```
export default class ChildComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: props.latitude,
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('Before Mount: ' + this.state.latitude)
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Text>{'Mounted: ' + console.log(this.state.latitude)}</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, my console shows following result:

```
2:14:12 AM: Before Mount: null

2:14:12 AM: Mounted: null

2:14:12 AM: Mounted: 34.7821
```

Now `componentWillMount()` in my original code has an API call to a web service which depends on the value of `this.state.latitude` which clearly is not been passed, at least on the first render. On second render, when `this.state.latitude` value become available, only the `render()` function executes, but i need this value in my `componentWillMount()` function.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: you can handle it in ComponentDidMount

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was not able to receive props value in `componentWillMount` because this method only executes once, just before initial rendering. Since the props were not being passed from parent to child component on the first rendering, I solve the issue by using `componentWillReceiveProps` method in my child component. It receives the props on subsequent rendering and updates the original state in my child component. Which makes me able to access my state value. The code I use to solve is following:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      // update original states
      this.setState({
        latitude: nextProps.latitude,
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to call with "this" term your props.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: this.props.latitude,
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('Before Mount: ' + this.state.latitude)
  }
```

Comment: No, that's not it. The state value does print on the second render iteration with my given code.

Answer (score 0):

you get props inside

`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       // process your work
  }`